# Causal Inference: Selection Bias and Endogeneity

Tags: causality, endogeneity, dag, selection-bias, causal-diagram

I've encountered lots of causal inference terms and jargons (under the Neyman-Rubin potential outcome framework), and I had questions regarding their relationships:

I know that exogeneity E(e|X) = 0 is a regression assumption that can be violated by omitted variable bias, and that selection bias is an omitted variable issue (such as the Angrist & Pischke's example of hospitals).

How do **selection bias** and **endogeneity** relate to each other? Is the latter a proper subset to the former? Or are they equivalent? Or are they merely overlapping?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Related Questions:

[Causal Inference: Moderation and Mediation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/541852/causal-inference-moderation-and-mediation)

[Causal Inference: Ignorability and Collider](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/541853/causal-inference-ignorability-and-collider)

[Pearl's Front-door and Back-door](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/541855/pearls-front-door-and-back-door)

Comment: This is generic and multiple questions pooled into one.  Maybe narrow the concepts and providing references.

Comment: Consider splitting this into multiple threads so that there only is one question per thread.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I have edited this thread and divided it into more detailed sub-threads.