# Causal Inference: Ignorability and Collider

Tags: sampling, inference, causality, dag, causal-diagram

I've encountered lots of causal inference terms and jargons (under the Neyman-Rubin potential outcome framework), and I had questions regarding ignorability.

Is it the case that **ignorability** is always a no **sample selection bias** condition?

And is this term equivalent to saying no **collider**?

Related Questions:

[Causal Inference: Moderation and Mediation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/541852/causal-inference-moderation-and-mediation)

[Causal Inference: Selection Bias and Endogeneity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/541807/causal-inference-selection-bias-and-endogeneity)

[Pearl's Front-door and Back-door](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/541855/pearls-front-door-and-back-door)

Comment: Selection bias is just a single type of confounding. ignorability assumes there are no confounding biases caused by unmeasured/unobserved variables. (Selection bias is fine as long as you can adjust for it, which assumes you measured a rich enough collection of baseline variables).

Comment: Honestly, I do not know what a collider is, and just now reading the definition it seems like it's just a property of a node in the causal graph. I would not get too bogged down on the oversaturated terminology in causal inference. All you really need to understand right now is what is a confounder and intervention. Start with a concrete problem like ATE (average treatment effect) and write down the causal graph and work through the assumptions and identification. Pearl's NPSEM framework is useful as you can just write down how the data is generated causally andwork with a concrete structure.